# Can an app developed for iOS 12 be installed on an iPadOS

Tags: ios, ipad

Considering iOS 13 releasing iPadOS, Can an app developed for a lower iOS version be installed on iPadOS ? Or does it require that, the app be developed specifically for iPadOS,like Watch OS or Mac OS ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

iPadOS is still iOS, just being marketed differently. If you release an app built for iOS 12, or even versions below, your users on iOS 13 on iPhone or iPad will still be able to install your app. If you are talking about the development side, you'll need Xcode 11 to add proper support but it will be the same process as it was from iOS 11 to 12 and Xcode 9 to 10.